# ¿Se puede proporcionar un nombre a una expresión de función en javascript?

Tags: javascript, función-personalizada

¿una expresión de función (o sea declarar un función y asignarla a una variable)

```
var xxx = function(){return yyy};
```

puede tener nombre? (en el siguiente ejemplo 'zzz')

```
var xxx = function zzz(){return yyy};
```

Answer (score 2):

Se puede proporcionar un nombre a una expresión de función, y éste puede ser utilizado dentro de la función para referirse a sí misma, por ejemplo:

```
var xxx = function zzz(arg){
             return yyy + zzz(arg-1);
          }
```

Sin embargo el nombre 'zzz' no puede ser utilizado fuera de la función.

```
 var xxx = function zzz(arg){
             return yyy 
           } 
 zzz(arg);
```

Este codigo da error.

La llamada a la función debe ser:

```
 var xxx = function zzz(arg){
              return yyy 
           } 
 xxx(arg);
```